# how to disactivate @Before for a particular method?

Tags: testing, junit4, spring-test

I am writing a test class in java using spring and junit (actually I have "@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)" at the bottom of my class).

there is a method with @Before annotation that I want it not to be run before a particular test method(but not the rest). how can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Refactor to put that one test in a new test class which doesn't have @Before.
2. Refactor to put that one test in a new test class extending the original one that overrides @Before to do nothing.
3. Refactor to have all the other methods call the before method explicitly and remove the @Before annotation (I don't recommend you go with this one)